# Formula with IF, Or, And & Isnumber returns too many arguments error

Tags: arguments

I have created a formula which has resulted in too many arguments error. The formula is to return in  column G the value in column E provided that column D contains specific text and column b contains one of 4 different text values. The Isnumber function works

The formula i have created is:-

```
=If(
  or(b4="Electrical,B4="Mechanical",B4="Builderswork,B4="Street"),
  AND(Isnumber(search(*"MAT"),d4))
),E4,"")
```

I get a

> "too many arguments"

error message.

I have checked the locations of the comma and brackets several times bur cant see anything obviously wrong or am i  using the wrong functions

Comment: Check again ... To begin with: You have inbalanced parenthesis. Ie you have 5 opening `(` but 6 closing `)` parenthesis. And furthermore your `AND` does only have one argument. I reformatted your formula to visualize that better ...

Comment: And if I understand you right, you want something like this `IF(AND(OR(b4= ...), IsNumber(...)), E4, "")`